# Is there a computationally efficient algorithm which can map back and forth a multi-dimensional real number (R^n) to a single dimensional real (R)?

Tags: algorithms, sets, real-numbers

I believe its possible to achieve this with natural numbers.
The example below is for 2d to 1d conversions both ways, I do believe this generalizes to n-dimensions.

The mapping should work in a way that means that there is a total order of the elements on each side of the mapping, ie. moving through one space in order should move through the other space in order, i.e. between their corresponding min's and max's.

I think the question I'm asking is:

`Does there exist an f: R^n -> R, where f is invertible , a bijection and there are total orders on R^n and R, where there is a bijection between these orders`

I think would get the orders requirement for free if the invertible bijection exists?

I'm looking to apply this to the Real numbers. I realize the examples below use modulo which is not supported in Real arithmetic. Could this be possible for the reals as I believe there is a bijection between R^n and R.
Is there an algorithm for this that exists already?

Assume width is the known length of one of the 2d dimensions.

1d to 2d integer:

```
y = index / width;
x = index % width;
```

2d to 1d integer:

```
index = x + width * y;
```

Comment: while calculating x and y, you are using input and width as parameters so it still is in 2 dimensions.

Comment: if you are working with fixed precision reals, then you can simply concatenate and split them at a fixed position. The number after concatenating could be located on the number line and before concatenating on the x-y plane.

Comment: I think you would want to check the Hilbert's curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Applications_and_mapping_algorithms

Comment: The lengths and widths of the dimensions will be known, i.e. mapping between R^2 and R where R is [0,1], so it should be some kind of arithmetic operation, modulo is defined for integers but not so well for reals, so not sure how it will work. However could just use fixed precision reals and which map to integers, hence it should work. However I missed another requirement which I will also add to the question. As R increases so should R^2, and vice versa, basically they should have a bijection between their orders if you know what I mean?

Comment: How about just interleaving their binary or decimal digits?

Comment: Please define order-preserving more precisely.  Why is this a question about computer science?  It looks like a question about math to me.  Please don't add clarifications in the comments -- instead, [edit] the question to improve it.

Comment: Ok i have tried again

Answer (score 1):

The answer is of course yes.  Take any bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and define a total ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as follows: for each $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we define $x<y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$.  This defines a total order on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and now $f$ plus this total order meets your condition.

(See also [Hilbert's space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).)

I suspect your formulation of the question doesn't match what you really want to know.

Comment: Thank you, yes I also meant it must be computationally efficient, i've updated the question. I guess this doesn't exist for the reals as there is no well-defined modulo operation for the reals?

Comment: Should I accept this answer and post a new question that includes the efficiency requirement?